# Extract information from a string - java

Tags: java, android

I have created an application for monitoring incoming SMS messages using broadcast receiver. The app monitors specific messages from a specific sender. I am trying to extra certain information from the message which has this format:

**PF56S55yy** Confirmed.You have received Ksh**6,495.00** from **Guaranty Trust Bank Limited 910201** on **5/6/21** at **10:07** PM New M-PESA balance is Ksh10,103.45.  Separate personal and business funds through dummytext la dummytext on *377#.

The information that i need if in bold format as seen above i.e

code: PF56S55yy
amount received: 6,495.00
from: Guaranty Trust Bank Limited 910201
date: 5/6/21
time: 10:07

Comment: This isn't all that difficult, if all the other parts are fixed texts. what have you tried so far?

Comment: I am not that good with java. I have very little experience. I just need a guide. Thanks

Comment: a guide? You can do all of this using only methods of the String class: https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/String.html
This is the basics of the basics, it doesn't require you to be good or have much experience, it does require you to try, though

Comment: @user15793316 if all the non-required text is fixed, regex might be a bit overkill

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using `regex` you can extract required information.

Try regex at https://regex101.com/r/ifuwVg/1

Java Code:

```
import java.util.regex.Matcher;
import java.util.regex.Pattern;

public class Example {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        final String regex = "^([a-zA-Z0-9]+)\\s{1}[a-zA-Z0-9\\.\\s]+Ksh([0-9,.]+)\\sfrom\\s([a-zA-Z0-9\\.\\s]+)\\son\\s([0-9/]+)\\sat\\s([0-9:]+)\\s[A|P]M\\s.*$";
        final String string = "PF56S55yy Confirmed.You have received Ksh6,495.00 from Guaranty Trust Bank Limited 910201 on 5/6/21 at 10:07 PM New M-PESA balance is Ksh10,103.45. Separate personal and business funds through dummytext la dummytext on *377#.";

        final Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile(regex, Pattern.MULTILINE);
        final Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(string);

        if(matcher.find()) {
            String code = matcher.group(1);
            String amountReceived = matcher.group(2);
            String from = matcher.group(3);
            String date = matcher.group(4);
            String time = matcher.group(5);

            String format = "code: %s amount received: %s from: %s date: %s time: %s";
            System.out.println(String.format(format, code, amountReceived, from, date, time));
        }
    }
}
```

Output of above program:

```
code: PF56S55yy amount received: 6,495.00 from: Guaranty Trust Bank Limited 910201 date: 5/6/21 time: 10:07
```